# Python and Overpass: Cannot get a complete address list even though I can see it on the map

Tags: python, overpass-api

I am new to OSM and running a Python script like this https://pypi.org/project/osmxtract/ to get building addresses and polygons of my street via Overpass.

I get a list. The list changes depending on my buffer but in weird ways: a small buffer yields no addresses, a large buffer generates a long list but does not include my address or most other local streets.

Is the buffer also changing the zoom so the server has to dump less detail for a bigger area? 
Should I be specifying values to keep the building list short and limit my features?

```
lat, lon = location.geocode('Stretford, Manchester')
bounds = location.from_buffer(lat, lon, buffer_size=1000)

query = overpass.ql_query(bounds, tag='building')
response = overpass.request(query)

feature_collection = overpass.as_geojson(response, 'polygon')
with open('building.geojson', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(feature_collection, f)

geodataframe = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(feature_collection)
```